# What data mining tools do you use?

Tags: open-source, data-mining

Besides the two well-known Open Source tools RapidMiner and Weka, are there any other good tools (either Open Source or Commercial), which you can recommend for data mining?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

My money is on [**R**](http://www.r-project.org), see e.g. the [Machine Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) task view.

Answer (score 2):

How about the open source Orange data mining toolkit.

http://www.ailab.si/orange/

Answer (score 2):

You can look at my project - [Data Mining SDK](http://datamining.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

According to the KDnuggets Poll 2011, RapidMiner once more is the most widely used data mining solution world-wide:
http://www.kdnuggets.com/2011/05/tools-used-analytics-data-mining.html

Answer (score 1):

If it is commercial software the following two are awesome

1. SAS
2. [SPSS](http://www.spss.com)

Comment: SAS is great, but has a steep learning curve. I've not used other software, though, so perhaps the learning curve is pretty standard.

Comment: could you provide a link to download SAS open source !

Answer (score 1):

Another very powerful opensource tool is Knime. In some respects it is better than RapidMiner. As for commercial here's what I've tried:

```
1.Polyanalyst
2.SPSS Clementine
3.Kxen
4.Statistica Data Miner
5.MATLAB
```

I like Polyanalyst the best. But it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

According to the yearly KDnuggets Polls 2007, 2008, and 2009, RapidMiner is the most widely used Open Source Data Mining Solution among data mining experts world-wide:
[KDnuggets Data Mining Tool Poll 2009](http://www.kdnuggets.com/polls/2009/data-mining-tools-used.htm)

RapidMiner is open source and 100% Java, RapidMiner is much more flexible and offers significantly more functionality than Weka and KNIME.

Answer (score 1):

JDMP http://www.jdmp.org/

Answer (score 0):

The data mining tool I used(also machine learing tools):

Weka: classfication, clustering, association rule, decision tree......

Cluto: clustering

libsvm: classification

And from many posts, I find there still other famous tools which I haven't used:

Orange

R

RapidMiner

SAS

SPSS

There must be other useful tools that I'm not aware of.

Comment: do you know where I can download SAS open source and it's documentation ...